# Проверка двух строк на Java

Tags: java

Пытаюсь сделать антиплагиат проверку на джаве в своем методе проверяю таким вот образом

```
 if (split.trim().toLowerCase().equalsIgnoreCase(antis.trim().toLowerCase())) {
                        anti.append(antis).append(" ");
                    }
```

где переменная split - это с клиента приходить какой то длинный текст 
а переменная antis это с базы 
вся проблема в том что когда запускаю свой запрос в фасаде то antis  всегда равен последнему запису

код с фасада

```
public String getText() throws Exception{
        Query query = null;
        String answ = null;
        query = em.createQuery("Select m.text from MyBd m ");
        List<String> strings = query.getResultList();
        for (String answer: strings) {
            answ = answer;
        }
        return answ;
    }
```

Comment: А что должно быть?

Comment: там в базе много записей он берет только последнюю

Comment: Еще раз спрошу, а что должно быть?

Comment: он должен вытащить все записи с фасада

Comment: На каждой итерации цикла вы перезаписываете переменную answ, а потом возвращаете её значение на последней итерации.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Код фасада должен быть другой для вытаскивания всех записей.

```
public ArrayList<String> getText() throws Exception{
        Query query = null;
        ArrayList<String> answ = new ArrayList();
        query = em.createQuery("Select m.text from MyBd m ");
        List<String> strings = query.getResultList();
        for (String answer: strings) {
            answ.add( answer ) ;
        }
        return answ;
    }
```

тогда результатом будет массив строк, из БД. А дальше проверяйте тоже в цикле